# SSH call inside ruby, using %x

Tags: ruby, string, bash, ssh, awk

I am trying to make a single line ssh call from a ruby script. My script takes a hostname, and then sets out to return the hostname's machine info.

```
return_value = %x{ ssh #{hostname} "#{number_of_users}; #{number_of_processes}; 
              #{number_of_processes_running}; #{number_of_processes_sleeping}; "}
```

Where the variables are formatted like this.

```
number_of_users = %Q(users | wc -w | cat | awk '{print "Number of Users: "\$1}')

number_of_processes = %Q(ps -el | awk '{print $2}' | wc -l  | awk '{print "Number of Processes: "$1}')
```

I have tried both %q, %Q, and just plain "" and I cannot get the awk to print anything before the output. I either get this error (if I include the colon)

`awk: line 1: syntax error at or near :`

or if I don't include the slash in front of $1 I just get empty output for that line. Is there any solution for this? I thought it might be because I was using %q, but it even happens with just double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this problem is:

```
%q(users | wc -w | awk '{print \"Number of Users: \"\$1}')
```

Where you have to use `%q`, not `%`, not `%Q`, and not `""`
You must backslash double quotes and the dollar sign in front of any awk variables

If somebody could improve upon this answer by explaining why, that would be most appreciated

Though as Steve pointed out I could have improved my code using `users | awk '{ print \"Number of Users:\", NF }'`
In which case there is no need to backslash the NF.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to capture the output of the command and return the output as a string:

```
number_of_users = `users | wc -w | cat | awk '{print "Number of Users:", $1}'`

puts number_of_users
```

Results on my system:

```
48
```

But you can improve your pipeline:

```
users | awk '{ print "Number of Users:", NF }'

ps -e | awk 'END { print "Number of Processes:", NR }'
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm guessing I could improve a lot of the commands I'm using with the stuff from above, like `ps -el | awk '{print $2}' | grep 'R' | wc -l | awk '{print "Number of Processes Running: " $1}'` and `grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d@ -f1 | awk '{print "Model Name: " $0}'`, but it didn't really answer my question.